# How to use applicationData in PKPaymentRequest (ApplePay)?

Tags: ios, applepay, application-data

I want to set pass through variable on Apple Pay, I set the `NSDictionary` as **JSON** data like:

```
PKPaymentRequest *request = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
[request setApplicationData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"name":@"USER_NAME"} options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]];
```

Now inside:

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status))completion;
```

I am able to access applicationData as

```
NSError* jsonError;
NSDictionary* dataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:payment.token.paymentData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
```

*dataDict[@"header"][@"applicationData"]* contains application data

but the data is encoded, I want to get `@{@"name":@"USER_NAME"}` from applicationData.